# Proof/disproof of conjecture involving noncentral Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: asymptotics, stirling-numbers

I have a conjecture I am looking at involving the noncentral Stirling numbers of the second kind (for explanation of these numbers, see e.g., [Koutras 1982](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271536/1-s2.0-S0012365X00X02117/1-s2.0-0012365X82900565/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEI7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDG%2BH06%2Blrop7MUVcNyLSrfz%2Bkd%2Feo1WZQmjh0iOzFQMQIgYnZyKnzUwwO9J%2B%2BZDHq23mJ4xF%2BfZ4bXjyIaShuTsdkqgwQIh%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDHlZlsmVjyunYfE5kirXA7uUyKidh%2Bmxs8lum%2Fy3nkl7Hzqv7sogwy6samLlqcwUm9%2BlIcWppu8iRl3KyXt0bBzGE987ygYBU4aUJJbIpey49sIQZeaReXKkJu2yW2Q1Itq7rhyWGbHLCZxXt%2Be7b5FQyD2JMBPLUq%2F5Ir9s3xB7%2FTJtR13IX%2Fp3bZFGM7W08YK6c1kdZFMyByZUYu7sbv92aQOERfypfF0m90QU3nXJgQLQh7sLnQo6a0SahmdDZDcP5LJJww5M3wxy6X76UhwzbUuHFjAX6Obmp8Gy%2FS0eeFZ%2Fz1DLleIQSOtzd6EIO%2FaaxkUz3otqP857SO7xuzmrrNCZ%2FK9CDmWkZBflNTLKfRKQ6K21dCx1PGJQh91hdIUQhaQAikmiRd8R5ZDOkyJEfQA%2BFz%2BLkqSnIO1l3RVhV%2BrGBhwKqmIY1ALLF9cWOEsF7TiHtwu6FX4YHs5OXfsYICzRp7XrPm8uXZV8kELbjzZuOgZ2vysueQ3IEJ6gWMxALpkbWYRdz7a6zuSsBIEOjfOKixf8cd7red2lVji7LstKH9KKieeqsz2Kr9p5yc9hBPPbNKIXthP%2Bm2Q1CAxGrxuDXi3Z97WRRddGLPT7dM%2BOPDHjYrtlv6hwSguzDnawL7d1JjDTiKCOBjqlAcFCIBhpGijtHkp4KRvd3M8hV2JBDnFJYKTS16xljPJ0ztbKEc%2BIeSLr6J%2FkDTxjHl%2B1KZ5uUg7bFloDwVUGfLNU8QWrpe9DIU1wNkdjaUo8K8wIlhjnSrmV31uytNxOnV8PsjOG9ZZBNuO1b9Foa9Mx9AWq9mtpGernpjHSp0LqETfIxYT99V4spUNig02ig%2F8lERmLqepKaGYSfKYVOIhFSPLrLw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211226T063745Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY5RXT722O%2F20211226%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=e0f634e63ed23f4dc997a3c3ddefe39f222e8f4d214ab5e9d6793e1bed483e8b&hash=ffc565c956394c1365ad9e6b50c1d022721021467ff10853eede64f4991dfe71&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0012365X82900565&tid=spdf-c8c1a2e5-2d5d-4487-bcca-6615c6c2c05c&sid=6a7602766f3ef84dee8b1bc9b41d1ec92fbfgxrqa&type=client)).  I'm having some difficulty proving it.  I've tried expanding the noncentral numbers to the central Stirling numbers but this is just making a mess.  Can anyone prove/disprove this?

> **Conjecture:** For large $n$ we have the asymptotic equivalence:$$\frac{S_a(n,k)}{S_b(n,k)} \sim \bigg( \frac{k+a}{k+b} \bigg)^{n-k}.$$
> (If necessary, you can add the conditions $k \geqslant 0$, $a>0$ and $b>0$ since that is the case I am interested in.)

Comment: I would probably use the generating functions of $S_a$ and $S_b$ to obtain an asymptotics for them and take the ratio of the two asymptotic approximations. See how Temme does it for the ordinary Stirling numbers of the second kind: https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/2304/2304D.pdf

Answer (score 3):

According to formula (2.6) of the link provided by the OP,

$$ \tag{1}S_a(n,k)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^{m-k}\binom{k}{m}(m-a)^n $$

According to formula (2.3) of reference [1]

$$ \tag{2} B_{n-k}^{-k}(-a) = \frac{(n-k)!}{n!} \sum_{m=0}^k (-1)^{m-k}\binom{k}{m}(m-a)^n $$

where $B_n^k(x)$ are the generalized Bernoulli polynomials, and are implemented in Mathematica as NorlundB[n,k,a].  Thus it is easy to conclude

$$S_a(n,k) = \binom{n}{k}B_{n-k}^{-k}(-a) $$
Reference [1] states asymptotic expansions for various regimes of parameter variation. The OP did not specify how $a$ and $k$ vary with respect to $n,$ so I assume they are fixed and $a<k.$(and rather small for numerical calculation.)  Then formula (2.8) applies, and by cancelling factors without $a$ or $b$ dependence one easily obtains

$$ \tag{3} \frac{B_{n-k}^{-k}(-a)}{B_{n-k}^{-k}(-b)} \sim \frac{\big( 1- \exp{(-\frac{n}{k-a})}\big)^k\big(k-a\big)^n} {\big( 1- \exp{(-\frac{n}{k-b})}\big)^k \big(k-b\big)^n} $$

The only way to get something that looks like the OP's conjecture is to assume the argument of the exponential is small, but this is impossible for fixed $a$ and $k.$  (Furthermore, the signs on $a$ and $b$ differ from the proposed asymptotics.) For a numerical example, let's calculate the left-hand side of (3) versus the RHS with n=50, a=4/10, b=7/10, and k=4.  Then the LHS = 77.522527 and the RHS = 77.522342 for about a 0.000024% error.

$[1]$ *Large degree asymptotics of generalized Bernoulli and Euler polynomials,* J. Lopez, N. Temme in J. Math Analysis & Applic. 363 (2010) 197-208.